# How to capture all form inputs that have changed, except those in a specfic class using jQuery 1.4

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have this code to capture all form inputs and it's working, however, I'm trying to exclude those in a certain div that is a dropdown that is common to the jsp's.  I assigned the div to a class for this as a possible solution.

Here is the original working line of code:

```
$(':input', document.formName).change(function() { ...
```

then I use an if statement:

```
if($('.className:not(.selected)')){ 
do something ...
```

but the if statement isn't right somehow.  What is the best way to do this?  Is there a way to combine everything in one statement or is the if block the right way and if so, what is the correct syntax to exclude a class?

Comment: You should show us the DOM structure.

Comment: I don't think the client would appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) in your selector to exclude elements with the class `.selected`

```
$(':input', document.formName).not('.selected').change(function() { ...
```

or even

```
$(':input:not(".selected")', document.formName).change(function() { ...
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/GS5e4/1/).

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use the `if` statement itself, if the selector is doing the filtering. If you could add the css class (say `excluded`) on the inputs themselves rather than a surrounding `div`, the below would work

Either:

the [`.not` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/): ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/Ts6RA/))

```
$('form').find(':input').not('.excluded').change(function() {
    //your code
});
```

or the [`:not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/): ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/Ts6RA/2/))

```
$('form').find(':input:not(".excluded")').change(function() {
    //your code
});
```